# how to make a column editable in kendo grid from a button click

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've seen how you can make a column editable / non-editable within a kendo grid, but how do I make a certain column editable from a button outside the grid?

The grid starts off as not editable but when a button is clicked outside the grid, it is to make "Column 2" editable. Can this be done?

```
<button id="Edit">Edit</button>
<div id="grid"></div>

$('#grid").kendoGrid({
    pageable: true,
    editable: false,
    etc...
    columns: [
       { field: "Column 1", title: "Column 1" }
       { field: "Column 2", title: "Column 2" }
       { field: "Column 3", title: "Column 3" }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Grid's [`setOptions` method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) to enable editing on external button click:

```
$("#Grid-ID").data("kendoGrid").setOptions({ editable: true });
```

This will make all **bound** columns editable, unless you have disabled editing for specific fields via the `schema.model.fields` configuration, as shown in the [Grid Batch Editing example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing).

```
SomeFieldName: { editable: false }
```